# Check if directory is created (Wordpress and/or PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress, directory

I'm relatively new to PHP and I'm trying to write my own plugin. Upon plugin activation it will run the following function:

```
function kb_create_uploadfolder () {
     global $wpdp;

     $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
     $upload_dir = $upload_dir['basedir'] . "/plugin_uploads";
     $upload_dircheck = wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir);    
}
```

I didn't bother to check whether the directory already exists before creating it since I figured it won't overwrite anything or delete the contents if it does. Correct me if I'm wrong.

The thing is however, I would like to check if the creation of the directory was succesful or not but I can't figure out how to get this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`is_dir()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php):

```
if(is_dir($upload_dircheck))
{
    echo "It is a dir";
}
else
{
    echo "Sorry, non-existent or not a dir";
}
```

Also, `mkdir()` doesn't delete or overwrite existing contents, it just creates a directory if it does not yet exist.

Comment: Thanks for verifying my earlier thoughts about mkdir()!

Answer (score 1):

Try [`is_dir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP 4 or newer then you can use the [`is_dir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) function.